# Wow Slider appears on all pages except one why?

Tags: magento-1, javascript

View this "wowslider" works here: https://www.allbookcovers.com

1.) but once you goto this single category made in Magento Version 1.5 CE as a page for product it starts breaking and showing the actual code:

https://www.allbookcovers.com/new-products/ipads-covers

2.)
https://www.allbookcovers.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=TS727&x=0&y=0also when ever the search tool is used in upper left, it gives results of next page but wipes away the banner , why?

-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it, it was of course requiring the slash / for an absolute url, it was given to me as a relative url.